Subharmonic function dominated by logarithm at infinity
I am currently reading the article Distributional and Lq norm inequalities for polynomials over convex bodies in Rn and I'm in particular interested in one statement, for which the authors do not provide much explaination (maybe it would be obvious if I had sufficient nowledge about harmonic analysis, which I have not).

If $u:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a subharmonic function such that
$
\limsup_{|z|\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{u(z)}{\log|z|} \leq 1,
$
then
$$
u(x) = \text{constant} + \int_{\mathbb{C}} \log|x-\zeta|d\mu(\zeta)
$$
where $\mu$ is a positive measure of mass at most one.

Question: Why does the above result hold ?
I am not quite sure to understand where this result comes from.
I feel that this must yields from Riesz's theorems and Liouville's theorem for subharmonic functions, although I am not shure how to properly combine everything.
Thank you in advance for any help !

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
